# JSONP call gives me an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [json with google geocoding api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681928/json-with-google-geocoding-api)
>   [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

```
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true&callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It gives me this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token **or** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token **or** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590608/jquery-getjson-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-error

Comment: Use the network section of your web inspector (because you're using one, aren't you?) to get the response and understand the problem. Then post it here.

Comment: Tats is correct http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true&callback=test shows `{...}` (instead of `test({..})`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a JSONP response from google maps , which it doesnt support.

Try this instead,

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>  
    $(function(){   
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714224,-73.961452);
        geocoder.geocode(
            {latLng  : latlng }, 
            function(dataObject, statusObject) {
                console.log(dataObject);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```